# Need help in creating a unique constraint in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

We have a WorkOrder table in Integration. I want to ensure the combination of WorkId,Key1,Key2,Key3  is unique.
But values in Key1 , Key2,Key3 columns are nullable and can be either null or ‘’.

I tried implementing this by the below index. But for some reason it is still allowing me to have 2 rows with the same combination of WorkId,Key1,Key2,Key3

```
Create Unique NonClustered Index WorkOrder_NCI_Uniqueness1
on WorkOrder (WorkId,Key1,Key2,Key3)
where [Key1] is null and [Key2] is null and [Key3] is null and WorkId is not null
```

Comment: Why do you add the WHERE part? What happens if you just create index by Key1, Key2, Key3

Comment: The above will create an `INDEX` to ensure that the value of `WorkId` is unique when all 3 of your Key columns have the value `NULL`, so if you are `INSERT`ing/`UPDATE`ing rows where *at least* one of your key columns has a non-`NULL` value then uniqueness of `WorkID` will **not** be enforced.

Comment: Yes this not working as it does not meet my requirements . ANy idea how we can do that?

Comment: @siggemannen since Key1, Key2, Key 3 are nullable fields - hence I had added WHERE condition to create filtered Index.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, since you don't write it exactly. Nullness has nothing to do with uniqueness. You don't explain HOW the uniquity should be enforced with regards to NULL values. Is all 3 nulls OK to have duplicate, is having 2 nulls OK to have duplicates etc.

Comment: if something is not working, please include the complete script and the values that doesn't work as you expect

Comment: Are you sure you didn't actually want `where [Key1] is not null and [Key2] is not null and [Key3] is not null and WorkId is not null` Please be very clear about what exactly you want to be unique, what is defined as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle NULL and '' as equivalent by means of a view using ISNULL(, '') or NULLIF(, '') for the Key columns.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MYVIEW WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT WorkId,ISNULL(Key1,'')Key1,NULLIF(Key2,'')Key2,NULLIF(Key3,'')Key3 FROM dbo.MYTABLE

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX MYVIEWINDEX ON dbo.MYVIEW(WorkId,Key1,Key2,Key3)
```

If there is a unique index on the table and you want an additional control for NULL and '' you can append “WHERE (Key1=''OR Key1 IS NULL)OR(Key2=''OR Key2 IS NULL)OR(Key3=''OR Key3 IS NULL)” to focus the indexed view on those values, comparable with a filtered index, and minimize the data duplication.